# RequstMapping: How to catch anything that that begins with path '/view/*'?

Tags: spring, application-server

its easy to intercept any request coming to a specific domain like

```
http://localhost/stuff
```

This would be something like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class JsController {

logger.info("Client hit stuff domain);

}
```

Easy enough

**Question:** How do you intercept ANYTHING that begins with domain `view`?

Example

```
http://localhost/view/someView1
```

logger.info("Client is within subdomain 'view");

```
http://localhost/view/someView2
```

logger.info("Client is within subdomain 'view");

```
http://localhost/view/js/helper.js
```

logger.info("Client is within subdomain 'view");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood, but this mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/**")
```

will catch every path starting with `/view`.

Comment: This will catch the requests although given that you have two different methods handling both view/ and view/** which method takes precedence when the path 'http://IP/view' is requested?

Comment: @stackoverflow As I understood it, you wanted a single handler method for all `/view` prefixed URLs. Is that not what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah your right I did ask that question. So you did answer it correctly. I'll have to re-ask the question. Thanks Sotirious